# Called service function from controller error "is not a function"

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

So as a title says I'm calling function in Service by other function in controller which start on **input[submit]** click. I get following error when I click this input:

> TypeError: authenticationService._register is not a function
>       at Object.$ctrl.registerSubmit (RegisterModalCtrl.js:14)

HTML:

```
<form method="post" 
      name="registerData" 
      id="registerData" 
      ng-submit="$ctrl.registerSubmit()">
```

controller function called on submit:

```
$ctrl.registerSubmit = function() {
    console.log('im in registerSubmit controller function');
    authenticationService._register(); // im line 14 obviously
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

service function called by controller function:

```
var _register = function(registerExternalData) {
    console.log('im in register service function');
    /*
        ...
    */
};
```

I inject my service in controller:

```
app.controller('RegisterModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$uibModalInstance', 'authenticationService',
function($scope, $location, $uibModalInstance, authenticationService) {
```

Comment: Have you tried this.authenticationService._register() ?

Comment: It changes error to "TypeError: Cannot read property '_register' of undefined" when i add keyword this

Comment: $ctrl are = this, at beggining of the control definition ?

Comment: yes I have  var $ctrl = this; just after app.controller() which I mentioned above. The function in controller is executed because console.log work correctly.

Comment: Provide the code for the `authenticationService`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using angular service (& not the factory) then instead of `var` use `this` to define function inside service (service is like a constructor function):

```
this._register = function(registerExternalData) {
    console.log('im in register service function');
    /*
        ...
    */
};
```

Everything else same, no need of any other change in your code.